# Rails 5 Action Cable Heroku - Cable Stream Stops After Page Reload

Tags: heroku, actioncable

I hope someone will have the time to help me with my code. I have been stuck in using Active Job in Action Cable using Rails 5 for over a month now and no one seem to find what's wrong in my code from where I am taking the course.

The app I am working on is expected to show 2 flash messages 
1. Thank you for your review (from AJAX)
2. A new comment was posted (from Javascript channel code)

and more from (from Javascript channel code)
3. Prepend the new comment 
4. Refresh Raty rating
5. Fade out the flash messages

However, action cable only transmits items 2,3,4 for the a new comment. Once the page is reloaded action cable stops streaming.

My remote repo can be found here - [Sample Application](https://github.com/afide26/afbikeberlin)

And the sample app can be found here: [Demo Application](https://cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com)

My starting codes for action cable are:

```
config/cable/yml
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: postgres://ybywuliqfewhzz:R4PgzgJ9IdaJ7_pdIlHkXaFkS2@ec2-54-235-221-102.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfuvk0kbffhdq5
```

Server Site Cable Code app/assets/javascripts/channels/product.js

```
App.product = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel:"ProductChannel"}, {
  connected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected: function() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    console.log("Hello");
    $('#cable-flash').show();
    $('.product-reviews').prepend(data.comment);
    refreshRating();
    $('.alert').delay(2000).fadeOut(3000);
  },

  listen_to_comments: function() {
    return this.perform('listen', {
      product_id: $("[data-product-id]").data("product-id")
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  App.product.listen_to_comments();
});
```

app/channels/product_channel.rb

```
class ProductChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "product_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def listen(data)
    stop_all_streams
    stream_for data["product_id"]
  end
end
```

app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    def disconnect

    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user
        if verified_user = request.env['warden'].user
          verified_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

config/environments/production.rb excerpt

```
 config.action_cable.url = "wss://cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com/cable"
  config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ['https://cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com','https://cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com']
end
```

The code is working perfectly in development but fails in heroku for mobile and for desktop it only works for one comment, after that action cable stops transmitting the job.

This is an excerpt from the log I receive from heroku after a page reload which shows that the product page stopped streaming.

```
016-09-14T11:53:02.035002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products/4" host=cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com request_id=ad8f16fc-ac0a-4fc6-bbaf-5182127bd89d fwd="115.64.68.87" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=75ms status=200 bytes=8698
2016-09-14T11:53:02.420634+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-93d18917a3b22de4e50a8d8e5993dc92db143d1f1bc5b1914661670b138d5995.css" host=cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com request_id=9012c627-feb5-4b38-8fa6-3b20cbf1ed20 fwd="115.64.68.87" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2016-09-14T11:53:02.303375+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-09-14T11:53:02.303306 #3]  INFO -- : Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 115.64.68.87 at 2016-09-14 11:53:02 +0000
2016-09-14T11:53:02.303485+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-09-14T11:53:02.303443 #3]  INFO -- : ProductChannel stopped streaming from product:4
2016-09-14T11:53:02.693961+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-c4e466ef03b0da2f06fb6383f1a946665201a62d89bc96973d1a3b473db1f32b.js" host=cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com request_id=bfc119a2-f74f-45e8-a6c4-eeb915d54807 fwd="115.64.68.87" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2016-09-14T11:53:03.527479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/star-off.png" host=cfbikeberlinapp.herokuapp.com request_id=4285511d-6809-4558-b57a-9a0ae7fb8751 fwd="115.64.68.87" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=258
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? i am getting a similar error...

Comment: same problem here too - anyone ever figure it out?